# How to use a binary executable which takes filenames as arguments in hadoop streaming?

Tags: streaming, hadoop, mapreduce

Say I have a binary executable which takes filenames as arguments, like 'myprog file1 file2', it reads from file1 and writes to file2. The binary executable does not take stdin and does not emit stdout. How can I use this binary executable as a mapper or reducer in hadoop streaming? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You would have to first save your data as a temporary file on local disk in order to use your program.  Then you can read the results from the file.

However, this defeats the purpose of using Hadoop to process your data.  The overhead of copying data to local disk and reading the results back into Hadoop-land would kill performance.

I would recommend making changes to your binary executable to allow i/o via stdin and stdout.

Comment: This is the method I am using right now, and the disadvantage is obvious as mentioned in your reply. Is there a more elegant way? Instead of using a temp file on disk, is it possible to wrap the stdin and stdout like a file? I tried using /dev/stdin and /dev/stdout and it doesn't work. The binary file is not made by me and I can't change it.